# fetching user id from mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a site in which i want to fetch the user id from this query and assign it to a variable so that i can set it in the SESSION variable.

But it is not working.

Here is the code

```
            $sql="Select user_id,username,password,access_id from temp_users where `username`='$email' and `password`='$password' and `access_id`='2' and 'status'='approved'";
        $res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if($sql!='0'){
          //$_SESSION['username']=$email;
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$row[0];
            echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
            exit;
        }
             header("Location:userpanel2.php");
        }
        else{
         echo 'Query has some problem';
        }

    }

}
else{
    echo 'Signin not set';
}
```

Comment: You should really hash your passwords. And while you are at it try to prevent the XSS vulnerability in there.

Comment: what is not working? What does the query return when you execute it in the msysql shell?

Comment: replace `if($sql!='0'){` by `if($res){`

Comment: See my answer, you have error in sql query...

Comment: try replacing `if($sql!='0')` with `if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0)`

Comment: **Your code is prone to SQL injection, and is therefore insecure.** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: It is not echoing the value of the session and when i change the code then i get the mysql_fetch_array expects parameter one to be a resource

Comment: @user2696320 And are You calling `session_start();` at the start of a script?

Comment: @shadyyx: if he will not call session_start(), it will still echo $_SESSION['user_id']; with a user_id value; just it will not remember it in $_SESSION after loading another site. Solution is, he has an error in his sql query, see my answer below.

Comment: @Legionar I know and I already upvoted Your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your sql query. Not 'status', but `status`

```
$sql="Select user_id,username,password,access_id from temp_users where `username`='$email' and `password`='$password' and `access_id`='2' and `status`='approved'";
```

Comment: MD5/SHA1 are not suitable for password encryption. You should use Blowfish.

Comment: Thats just suggestion, was not point of OPs question.

Comment: Right, but you shouldn't give out bad advice. MD5 and SHA1 are not suitable anymore. Anyone with a half decent graphics card can produce a rainbow table to crack MD5/SHA1.

Comment: -1 for a bad suggestion. Even if your answer solves OP's problem, suggesting MD5 or SHA1 or any non-cryptographically-secure hashing mechanism is both irresponsible and dangerous.

Comment: @Dan Lugg: LOL :D :D :D fys...

Comment: @DanLugg I think this question was about why is the login query not working. **Legionar** answered the question correctly, so why downvoting? Recommending using the right tools is only the side effect and is not mandatory though welcomed. But as there is also a comment from **h20000000** why to repeat the same many times? And instead of Your negative comment You should recommend what hashing algorithm should be used then.

Comment: @Styphon: thats nice, but when you add salt, I dont think so anyone with a half decent graphics card can produce any rainbow table......

Comment: @shadyyx Hash algorithm recommendations are a whole different topic; one which has been beaten to death on SO. As far as this question is concerned, it's essentially off-topic, which is why I didn't digress into suggestions of my own. The provided suggestion, good intentions and all, was bad and dangerous. If anything, a link to one of the popular hash algorithm Q/As here would have been great. I've removed the down-vote since the suggestion has been removed.

Comment: @DanLugg That's nice. But still using at least `MD5` or `SHA1` (which are nowadays still used I guess in 95% of cases) are better than storing the passwords unencrypted (in plain text) at all. And as You mentioned, arguing about what hash alg. to use would be an OT here since the question was answered and at least a better security solution was proposed. Anyway, I had a security training about a month ago and `MD5` is still used though `MD5` or `SHA1` with salts was recommended as better solution and `bcrypt` as the best one nowadays...

Comment: @shadyyx **No**. "*But still using at least MD5 or SHA1 are better than storing the passwords unencrypted*". It's **not**. It results in a false sense of security. You think you've done your job just well enough to get by for now, and maybe you'll change it in the future, but you don't. There is no "good enough for now"; there's good, and bad. And `MD5/SHA*` are bad. (*editorial note: it's not "encrypted", it's hashed; encryption is reversable*)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in the condition

```
if($sql!='0'){
```

should be something like this:

```
if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
```

But as people commented, the $sql query should be better protected by using mysql_real_escape_string.

There is also a major error between ` and ' for status=approved

Comment: That is not little error, but major error :) others are suggestions, which also have to be done.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers and advices